# comprehensive tutorial about using AVAssetReader with Audio Queue/Streaming Services

Tags: ios, streaming

I'm working on an app that allows a user to select music tracks on their iphone, listen to it and share it with another person live so that the other person can listen to the same song in sync.

i've managed to get the following prototype [working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076374/audio-streaming-services-failing-to-recognize-file-type): manually add a file to the bundle i'm working with, then decode it using [AudioFileReadPackets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html) and sending it over the network using GKSession.

On the receiving end.. I use audio queue/streaming services to read the stream and play the music (ie AudioFileStreamOpen, AudioFileStreamParseBytes, AudioQueueNewOutput, AudioQueueStart etc. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076374/audio-streaming-services-failing-to-recognize-file-type) for more details).

That said, I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487568/audiofileopenurl-ipod-library) that I can't simply read a file from the iphone's file system and decode it.. rather I gotta use the AVAssetReader and so on. There are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972677/reading-audio-samples-via-avassetreader) of doing that on Stack Over Flow, but they focus on the immediate technical implementation rather than explaining the big picture.. I couldn't find much comprehensive guid or documentation from Apple's developer guide website (see how they describe [CMSampleBuffer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/Reference/reference.html) for example; function parameters have no descriptions etc).

Any links/books/ etc that may lead me in the right direction here? Specifically about accessing audio files in the iPod library and segmenting them using AVAssetReader such that they can be sent in a streaming fashion over a network, to be played via audio [queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343)/streaming services

Answer (score 1):

I found this book to be amazingly helfpul: [Learning Core Audio: A Hands-On Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007R3U9W2)